# matching two columns in excel with slight difference in the spelling

Tags: vba, excel, analysis, data-manipulation

I am working on huge excel sheets from different sources about the same thing. The way the sources report it and write down information is different. So, for example, one would write the location as "Khurais" whereas the other would write it as "Khorais".

Since both of these files are contain important information, I would like to combine them in one excel sheet so that I can deal with them more easily. So if you have any suggestion or tool that you think would be beneficial, please share it here.

P.s. The words in the excel sheet are translations of Arabic words.

Comment: Why not use the original arabic then, that should match I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use FuzzyLookup, a macro that allows you to do appropriate matching. It worked really well for me in the past and is actually really well documented.

[image: FuzzyLookup]

You can find it here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/195635-fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.html including examples on how to use it.

Hope that helps!

PS obviously you can also use it stricly within VBA (not using worksheet functions)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Levenshtein distance to determine if two words are "close" to each other. Based on that you could match.

Answer (score 0):

The ***Double Metaphone*** algorithm springs to mind.  It attempts to convert strings into phonetic representations.  For example, "Folly" and "Pholee" should have the same phonetic code.

If you could generate these codes, you could then match your records based on them, instead of the strings.

Here's an article that explains, along with sample VBA code:
https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/965241-fuzzy-string-matching-double-metaphone-algorithm

Hope that inspires you :)